# Proof: Given a $C^1$ parametrization of $f=f(x,y):\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$, substitute variables $(x,y) = (s+t,s-t)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, parametric

I'm studying Mathematical Analysis and trying to solve example problems as I go. Specifically, this problem comes after an introduction to $C$ parameterizations of $r:I\subseteq\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$.

> We have a $C^1$ function $f = f(x,y): \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$
> where we switch variables $(x,y) = (s+t,s-t)$.
>
> Prove that $\left( \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right )^2 - \left( \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right )^2 = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

I understand that it's asking me to calculate partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$, then substract them, but I did that and yielded nothing useful.

Plus, shouldn't I be doing something with $C^1$, which gives us that $f$ is continuously derivable in $\mathbb R^2$, and that $f'$ is also continuous? How could I put that into play?

I'm completely stalled, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the map $\bar\gamma(s,t) = (s+t,s-t)$.

When you make the change of variables, you are obtaining a new function $f(\bar\gamma(s,t))$; the equation you are asked to prove combines these 2 functions. You need to be able to compute the derivates $f(\bar\gamma(s,t))_s$ and $f(\bar\gamma(s,t))_t$ in terms of $f_x$ and $f_y$.

Here is where $f$ being $C^1$ comes to play; it lets us write:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = f_x + f_y,$$

and similarly for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = f_x - f_y$.

Comment: +shost71 If I am not provided for the formula of $f$, how can I calculate $f_x$ or $f_{s+t}$ and $f_{s-t}$? Also, how does the bottom part of your answer help us in this instance? Vote up for your concern in my problem, in any case.

Comment: You do not need to calculate $f_x$ or $f_y$, if you replace the expressions for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ in your equation you obtain: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = (f_x + f_y)\cdot (f_x - f_y) = (f_x)^2 - (f_y)^2$, which is the equation asked for.

Comment: The meaning behind this is that even if you don't know anything about the function $f$ (other than it being $C^1$), when you make this change of variables, whatever $f_s$ and $f_t$ are is linked to what $f_x$ and $f_y$ are. A small change in $s$ is a small change in $x$ plus a small change in $y$ - you are moving in a direction oblique to the xy axis, and the $C^1$ condition means that near a given point these small changes add up linearly - does this make sense?

Comment: +shost71 Thank you very much for both of these clarifications. I'm accepting the answer, I really appreciate your help. What you wrote makes sense and is practical, but in an exercise-answer environment, do I need to clarify how I went from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$? Is this a theorem or definition, or will I need to explain it as you did above, with words? Same for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Actually yes, it is a theorem - you may want to check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions

Comment: ...Sorry, I didn't realize it was just the chain rule.

Comment: I believe saying it is $C^1$ and mentioning the chain rule is enough clarification in this; you are welcome, and I am sorry I did not bring up the chain rule by its name beforehand.